# How can I turn an op address into the right kind of B::OP?

Tags: perl, perl-xs

In a running Perl program if I have an Op address (either by [B::Concise](https://metacpan.org/pod/B::Concise), [Devel::Callsite](https://metacpan.org/pod/Devel::Callsite) or via mysterious other ways) is there a simple way to cast that into the right kind of B::OP, short of walking an Opcode tree?

To try to make this clearer, here's some code:

```
use Devel::Callsite;
use B::Concise qw(set_style);
use B;

sub testing
{
    sub foo { callsite() };
    my $op_addr =  foo;
    printf "Op address is 0x%x\n", $op_addr;


    # I can get OPs by walking and looking for $op_addr,
    # but I don't want to do that.
    my $walker = B::Concise::compile('-terse', '-src', \&testing);
    B::Concise::walk_output(\my $buf);
    $walker->();   # walks and renders into $buf;
    print $buf;
}

testing();
```

When this is run you'll see something like:

```
$ perl /tmp/foo.pl
Op address is 0x2026940
B::Concise::compile(CODE(0x1f32b18))
UNOP (0x1f40fd0) leavesub [1] 
    LISTOP (0x20aa870) lineseq 
# 8:     my $op_addr =  foo;
         COP (0x1f7cd80) nextstate 
         BINOP (0x20aba80) sassign 
            UNOP (0x20ad200) entersub [2] 
                UNOP (0x1f39b80) null [148] 
                    OP (0x1fd14f0) pushmark 
                    UNOP (0x1f397c0) null [17] 
                        SVOP (0x1f39890) gv  GV (0x1fa0968) *foo 
            OP (0x2026940) padsv [1]
                ^^^^^^^^^^ 
....
```

So `0x2026940` is the address of a `B::OP` and and which according to [this](http://perldoc.perl.org/5.8.9/B.html#B%3a%3aOP-METHODS) has `next()`, `sibling()`, `name()` methods. If the address were say `0x20aa870` that would be the address of a `LISTOP` which has in addition a `children()` method.

I added B::Concise just to show what's going on. In practice I don't want to walk the optree, because I'm assuming/hoping that the address is in fact where that listop resides.

So perhaps there are two parts, first casting an address to `B::Op` which I believe is the parent class, but after that I'd like to know which kind of Op, (UNOP, BINOP, LISTOP) we are then talking about.

If I can get the cast part done, the second part is probably easy: all `B::OP`'s have a `name()` method, so from that I can figure out what subclass of OP I have.

**EDIT:**
ikegami's solution is now part of Devel::Callsite version 1.0.1 al though it isn't quite right.

Comment: Could you give some example code, please?

Comment: @Schwern ok code added. Does this make it clear?

Comment: [Crossposted from PerlMonks](https://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=1218517).

Comment: just in case it worked, I tried `B::svref_2object( bless(\$op_addr, 'B::SV')->object_2svref )`.  but it didn't :)

Answer (score 4):

This duplicates B's internal `make_op_object`.

```
use B qw( );

use Inline C => <<'__EOS__';

    static const char * const opclassnames[] = {
        "B::NULL",
        "B::OP",
        "B::UNOP",
        "B::BINOP",
        "B::LOGOP",
        "B::LISTOP",
        "B::PMOP",
        "B::SVOP",
        "B::PADOP",
        "B::PVOP",
        "B::LOOP",
        "B::COP",
        "B::METHOP",
        "B::UNOP_AUX"
    };

    SV *make_op_object(IV o_addr) {
        const OP *o = INT2PTR(OP*, o_addr);
        SV *opsv = newSV(0);
        sv_setiv(newSVrv(opsv, opclassnames[op_class(o)]), o_addr);
        return opsv;
    }

__EOS__
```

Example use:

```
use Devel::Callsite qw( callsite );

my $site = sub { return callsite() };
my $addr = $site->();
my $op = make_op_object($addr);
say $op->name;
```

Comment: So simple that I wonder why didn't I think of this before? ;-)  I will be adding this to Devel::Callsite in a future version.  Have any thoughts how much  if this varies over the various Perl versions. (I can check this myself, but if you happen to know...)

Comment: That may be true but `op_class` isn't in Perl versions 5.24 or earlier. You probably you can duplicate the 5.26 code in earlier versions though.

Comment: As I mention on perlmonks, although the `name` field is correct, the address changes and the other fields like parent are wrong. Sigh.

Comment: Re "*Have any thoughts how much if this varies over the various Perl versions.*", When mucking with not just Perl internals, but the internals of another module, breakage is to be expected. Just be sure to test your module with against dev releases of Perl, and the release candidates specifically. (p5p already does this for you, but it's best if you do it too.) p5p is always happy to help find a solution to breakage they cause.

Comment: Re "*`op_class` isn't in Perl versions 5.24 or earlier*", Then look at older versions of `ext/B/B.xs` to see what the module did before

Comment: Re "*the address changes and the other fields like parent are wrong*", You're printing the address of the B objects, not the address of the ops themselves. `printf("op: %s (0x%x), parent: %s (0x%x)\n", $op->name, $$op, $parent->name, $$parent);`

Comment: Thanks for the information and clarification. I need to put all of this on hold and focus on other things, but if/when I come back to this I'll use your suggestions with respect to Perl versions other than 5.26.